# Qt Controller Scripting select components in ComponentSelectionPage

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Im using a script to automate the QtFramework installation. I was used to select all components in the [ComponentSelectionPage](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html#component-selection-page). However nowadays with Qt5.10.0 this results in over 11 GB. So i would like to pick just the components i need. According to the documentation the `ComponentSelectionPage` has `selectComponent(id)` and `deselectComponent(id)` methods, `id` beeing the name of the component. So this should be doable.

However i can't find any documentation on the names/ids of the components. I tried several things like:

```
widget.selectAll()
widget.deselectComponent("MSVC 2013 64-bit")
widget.deselectComponent("MSVC*")
widget.deselectComponent("*MSVC*")
```

But neither of those work (i tried a bunch of differnt other combinations also). So does anybody know where to find documentation about component names of the default Qt Installer? I was already poking in their git repository but could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so i've found out how to solve this quite a while ago, if someone is still interested:

By running `strings <qt-installer-executable> | grep "qt\."` i was able to extract the names of the components. (Not sure if it was `strings` in windows, but a similar tool exists for sure).

An example output is then something like

```
....
qt.qt5.5121.gcc_64  
qt.qt5.5121.examples.qtpurchasing
qt.qt5.5121.doc.qtscript
qt.qt5.5121.qtdatavis3d.gcc_645
qt.qt5.5121.qtscript
qt.qt5.5121.doc.qtpurchasing
qt.qt5.5121.examples.qtscript
qt.qt5.5121.qtnetworkauth.gcc_64
...
```

along with a lot of other stings.

Comment: the `strings` trick no longer seems to work, since it seems that the binary no longer contains the options hardcoded, but instead pulls them from an XML file on the web. however, the new workaround then becomes to just look at the options in the XML file. Here is one such file: https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/qt5_5150/Updates.xml